# WPF DatagridComboboxColumn Keyboard operation

Tags: wpf, keyboard, operation, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am using a WPF datagrid with some DataGridComboboxColumn columns.

When I open the dropdown and select an entry with the mouse, the combo gets this selected entry as new current item.

When I navigate the drowdown with cursor keys and press ENTER, I woul expect the same, but it is not working.

How can I catch the appropriate events?

Comment: Do you want to open the combobox column by click enter in the Datagrid combobox column cell?

Comment: I open the combo dropdown by clicking the combo button, but after navigating in the dropdown list by using the cursor keys and pressing enter the active list item is not returned to the combo. The content of the combo is not changed. I would assume that this happens automatically, but maybe I have to hook up dome events for the combo manually?